# Pivot/Group data by key

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table (`survey_source`) like so where any of the values in `answer_text` can be populated or `NULL`:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| survey_id | submission_id | question_id | question_text | answer_text|
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| 001       | 2             | question1   | why?          | answer A   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| 001       | 2             | question2   | how?          | answer B   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| 001       | 5             | question1   | why?          | answer C   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| 001       | 5             | question2   | how?          | answer D   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| 001       | 5             | question3   | when?         | answer E   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

I would like to pivot this data such that the new columns are `survey_id`, `submission_id`, `question1`, `question2` and `question3` such that each submission is it's own row vs earch row being it's own question per submission.

If I use `CASE WHEN submission_id = 2 THEN answer_text` I can pivot the columns but I still get many rows due to the NULLS for other values.

Is there a way to get desired result? The only way I can think of is to select the unique submission_id's and then left join back to the table once per question which seems like overkill.

```
SELECT
    t1.survey_id,
    t1.submission_id,
    t2.answer_text as question1
FROM survey_source t1
LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                   submission_id,
                   answer_text
               FROM survey_source
               WHERE question_id = 'question1'
            ) t2
 ON t1.submission_id = t2.submission_id

 --- Repeat join to get question2
 --- Repeat join to get question3
```

---

Desired output table like so:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| survey_id | submission_id | question1 | question2 | question3 |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 001       | 2             | answer A  | answer B  | NULL      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 001       | 5             | answer C  | answer D  | answer E  |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY using MAX is a way to achieve this.

```
select
    survey_id,
    submission_id,
    max(case when question_id = 'question1' then answer_text end) as 'question1',
    max(case when question_id = 'question2' then answer_text end) as 'question2',
    max(case when question_id = 'question3' then answer_text end) as 'question3'
from survey_source
group by survey_id, submission_id
order by survey_id, submission_id;
```